# Does Spring load the same app context again every time it sees an import?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I was experimenting with overriding bean definitions and found out the following, which is slightly unrelated to the intended experiment.

I've two app context files.

App context 1:

```
<bean id="my" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="applicationContext-xml_1.xml" />
</bean>
```

App context 2:

```
<bean id="my" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="applicationContext-xml_2.xml" />
</bean>

<import resource="applicationContext-xml_1.xml"/>
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:applicationContext-xml_1.xml", "classpath:applicationContext-xml_2.xml"})
public class SpringOverridesTest {
   //...
}
```

I expected Spring to not load xml_1 again when it encountered *import xml_1* in xml_2. But that's not the case. Here's a trimmed version of the log:

```
[XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions()] - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext-xml_1.xml]
[XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions()] - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext-xml_2.xml]
[DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition()] - Overriding bean definition for bean 'my': replacing [... defined in class path resource [applicationContext-xml_1.xml]] with [... defined in class path resource [applicationContext-xml_2.xml]]
[XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions()] - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext-xml_1.xml]
[DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition()] - Overriding bean definition for bean 'my': replacing [... defined in class path resource [applicationContext-xml_2.xml]] with [... defined in class path resource [applicationContext-xml_1.xml]]
```

Question: It's surprising to see Spring loading the xml twice. Could someone explain the motivation?

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning you load :
applicationContext-xml_1.xml because you have made
`@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:applicationContext-xml_1.xml")` that loads the context with beans declared and instantiating them.

Then you load 
by second config in application context xml 2.

```
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:applicationContext-xml_1.xml", "classpath:applicationContext-xml_2.xml"})
```

But if you have noticed the beans with the same id are overriden that is loaded before in this case bean my from application context 1 is overrided with bean my of application context xml 2.

```
<bean id="my" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="applicationContext-xml_2.xml" />
</bean>
```

Then if you notice you load again application context 1 by :

```
<import resource="applicationContext-xml_1.xml"/>
```

**Importing Resource inside an aplication context is used to seperate logic between xml files.**

From this load that you do again by importing the appContext1 you override the bean my with bean from appcontext1.